# HTML5 youtubeplayer problems

Tags: windows, firefox, youtube, html5

I have a problem with html5 videoplayer on youtube. It's freezeng randomly (mostly after pause) and video loosing sound. I using the newest version of firefox on windows 7 x64 bits. I am working on PC.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange behaviour. If your computer is recent enough, there  mustn't be any problem on playing HTML5 videos on Youtube. If you like to continue with Firefox, try to use [this extension](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/10/20/force-flash-video-on-youtube-in-firefox/). If not, try another browser, like [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)